# how to play sound with change image repeately in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to write an app in Android Studio for my son that when he press a button, an image in image view  show and play a sound then after a few second ,automatically  the next image with next sound played, and so on, This process continues when another button is pressed to display another images and sounds.
How do I do this loop replay audio and switch images?
Thank you for your help

Comment: you can use ViewPager to switch between Images and you can use TimerTask and Timer(java.util) to set timer for them.                                                                                                     also see this-->https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask